# My sides on my box model built in HTML5 and CSS3 get pushed down with any text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I try putting extra text in the body of my homepage in the content are, it will distort and essentially push down the sidebar and advertising boxes I have set up on the side. This is a project for class and I have asked the teacher for assistance but she says the code is fundamentally good and she doesn't understand why it's doing this. Here is the code for my homepage and the css style sheet

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dio.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?  family=Exo:400,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="dio.js"></script>
        <style>
            #sidebar {
                background: olive;
                width: 20%;
                height: 1000px;
                float: left;
            }

            #advertising {
                background: olive;
                width: 20%;
                height: 1000px;
                float: right;
            }

            #footer {
                height: 50px;
                width: 1280px;
                background: black;
                text-align: center;
                clear: both;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            `
            <div id="header" id="png">
                <h1>DIO INC</h1></div>
            <h3>Today is <span id = "dtField"></span>
              </h3>
        </header>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <h2>DIO WEBSITE</h2>
            <nav>
                <details>
                    <summary>Page Content</summary>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p>Please click <a href="dioPage2.html">About Us</a> to view our inoformation</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>Please click <a href="dioPage3.html">Services and Pricing</a> to view our services</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>Please click <a href="dioPage4.html">Contact Information</a> to view our contact information</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </details>
                <nav>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
        <div id="advertising">
            <p>Please click
                <a href="http://www.ebay.com/sch/bananaman917_5/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_ipg=&_from="><img src="http://mssparky.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/ebay_logo.jpg" title=DIO width="150"></a> to view items for sale.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"><strong>Copyright &copy 2016</strong></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = initDate;

            function initDate() {
                var dayName = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
                var monName = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

                var now = new Date();
                var dtString = dayName[now.getDay()] + ", " + monName[now.getMonth()] + " " + now.getDate();

                document.getElementById("dtField").innerHTML = dtString;
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
h1 {
  color:#ADFF2F;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
  color:#ADFF2F;
  text-align: lcenter;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p, strong, summary, section, h3 {
  color:#ADFF2F;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a, h1, h2, p, strong, summary, section, h3 {
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
} 

a:link {
  color:#FF69B4;
}

a:active {
  color:#e03a3e;
}

a:hover {
  color:#e03a3e;
}

header {
  height:100px;
  width:1280px;
  background:black; 
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

html {
  background:url('trees.jpg') #98FB98 no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}

body {
  width:1280px;
  height:1100px00px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

content {
  float:left;
  height:1000px;
}

table {
  width:1280px;
  Height:1000px;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  color:#00FF00; 
  font-weight: bold;

}

thead {
  background: #3056A0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table > caption {
  font-weight: bold;
}

tfoot {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align:right;
  font-weight: bold;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #808000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

tbody tr {
  background: #808000
  font-weight: bold;
}

footer {
  height:50px;
  width:1280px;
  background:black;
  text-align:center;
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Is *all* that markup and CSS necessary to show the problem?

Comment: Off topic 1: You're not closing your `nav` element properly.

Comment: Off topic 2: Never use the word 'click' in a link. Ever.

Comment: Here's a simplified demo. Please add "extra text" as needed to show the problem, then add the updated fiddle's link to your question. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/4e7hurjx/

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer correct if you feel there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple. Your `#content` `#sidebar`and `#advertising` are all floating `left`, and all need a discreet width set to ensure they fit in your container (your `body` is acting as the containing width).

You have a width set on the `#sidebar` and `#advertising` but not the `#content`. So add a width rule.

```
#content {
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box; <---
  display:inline-block; <--
  width:60%; <--
  height:1000px;
}
```

Essentially, your content is expanding horizontally past 60%, and forcing the next element in the block flow (`#advertising`) under your `#content`; you've exceeded 100% of the available space.

Couple other things:

- `box-sizing:border-box` is also a good idea on structural elements
- don't set a `width` on the body. use wrapping element to contain content at a certain size.
- get a new teacher. Sorry, but these are newbie mistakes and your "teacher" should be able to easily see them.

Comment: how is `content` targeting this html tag `<div id="content">` ?

Comment: also, there are 2 sidebars, one left at 20% width and one right at 20% width, means you need to set the width to 60% not 80%.

Comment: selectors aside, the op is creating structural elements (grid style) and missing critical rules.

Comment: is that what hes trying to do? cripes. no wonder hes having issues.

Comment: basically take my answer and apply it to yours and you will be on the right track, your answer is better after the fixes are made lol

Comment: you at least gave a better reasoning :)

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the `#` for the `content` in your css, also add a width to the content like this:

```
 #content {
   float: left;
   height: 1000px;
   width: 60%;
 }
```

see fiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/op2vbsww/1/

Comment: I think hes still going to have a problem, as the element is still defaulting to display:block. "Does it naturally collapse horizontally if floating left?" he said to himself... Update. Yep. it does.